# How do I convert a Distance-time function to a velocity-time function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

> $x \begin{cases} t+3t^2, & \text{if  }   0 \le t \le 10\\ 260+5t, & \text{if } 10<t\le 20\\ 420-3t, &\text{if } 20<t \end{cases}$

> $x$ is the distance travelled by a racing car as a function of $t$,

I want to find the time at which the car is travelling the fastest.

How do I change this function as a velocity of the racing car as a function of time?

Do I have to differentiate every function in the piecewise function so I can find the velocity?

Comment: Yes, differentiate them.

Comment: You need to differentiate. (Technically the function is not differentiable at the break points.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert distance to velocity you differentiate. Since the function you are given is given in pieces, you will need to do piecewise differentiation. When doing this, you will get the following function for velocity:
$$v(t) =  \begin{cases} 6t+1, & \text{if  }   0 \le t \le 10\\ 5, & \text{if } 10<t\le 20\\ -3, &\text{if } 20<t \end{cases}$$

As copper.hat pointed out, you have to be careful at $t = 10$ and $t = 20$.

I am hoping you can take it from here.